# how to add the element in the array using the for loop in objective-c?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

is this the right way to do the same?

```
   nsmutablearray *myarray1     //have some data in it
    for (int i=0;i< [myarray1 count]; i++)
    {
          myArray2 = [NSMutableArray array];
         [myArray2 addObject:i];    
    }
```

and how can i print this value of myarray2.

Comment: are you trying to add element of one array into other array??

Comment: How do you want to print it? Is it just for debugging purpose?

Comment: You want to move the `myArray2 = [NSMutableArray array];` statement outside the `for` loop. If you did that, your code would work to copy the array, although Jim's solution with `arrayWithArray:` is better.

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to copy element of one array to other array then use following code:

```
 NSMutableArray *secondArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:firstArray];
```

If you want to print element value then depending upon data stored in your array you can print element.

i.e if array contains string object then you can print like this:

```
for(int i=0;i<secondArray.count;i++)
{
     NSLog(@"Element Value : %@",[secondArray objectAtIndex:i]);
}
```

if array contains any user define object then you can print like this:

```
for(int i=0;i<secondArray.count;i++)
{
     UserDefineObject *obj = [secondArray objectAtIndex:i];
     NSLog(@"Element Value with property value: %@",obj.property);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to create a new array containing the same elements as the old array is to use NSCopying or NSMutableCopying.

```
NSArray* myArray2 = [myArray1 copy];                // myArray2 is an immutable array
NSMutableArray* myArray3 = [myArray1 mutableCopy];  // myArray3 is an mutable array
```

If you want to print the contents of an array for debugging purposes:

```
NSLog(@"myArray2 = %@", myArray2);
```

If you want prettier printing for a UI, you'll need to iterate through as others have suggested.